Not satisfied with original formulation of my question — what steps can I take?
I have asked the question https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/48734/ on May 3rd. The question has been closed deleted by the community. However, I am against posting a new question, and I need that question to be edited for the following reasons:

I have asked this question on May 3rd when the Linguistics site has been the "Today's Featured Site". I really cannot live without asking questions of "Today's Featured Site".

I have five other questions on the Linguistics site, so we need to tackle that question too.


So, what details of clarity do I add about providing some evidence that computational linguistics has improved the understanding of Latin morphology?

For those who can't see deleted questions, this is the one:

The application of computational methods, such as machine learning and natural language processing, helps linguists to automate the analysis of Latin morphology.
How does computational linguistics improve the analysis of Latin morphology?

The problem is, this follows the same pattern as several of your other closed questions:

Make an assertion that isn't actually true
Ask us to explain and justify this assertion

This wouldn't necessarily be an issue if you had a source for the assertion—if you showed us the article it came from, for example, we could say things like "the author is misrepresenting her source, this is a more correct version", or "you've misunderstood what the author is saying", or even "this author is straight-up wrong".
But without a source—I'm assuming this comes from ChatGPT or the like, which at a fundamental level cannot back up anything it says—the question's just meaningless. We can't explain the reasoning behind ChatGPT nonsense because there is no reasoning there.

To add to Draconis' answer addressing this, I will also add that the particular change that led to me pointing Arunabh to the meta site (after they instead decided to comment on an unrelated question of mine) was editing the question Draconis quotes to instead read:


While New Orleans’ Congo Square is acknowledged as the heart and birthplace of American music, New Orleans’ unique Creole musical community was the engine for what became America’s early civil rights movement. 
Source

How did Creole musicians address cultural appropriation?

This was not just an edit that failed to address the close reasons, but changed it to a completely new question. If you wish to ask a new question, ask a new question, do not edit existing questions instead. Additionally, that new question is completely off-topic for this site.
I will also add that you have now added the following:

I have misunderstood what the author is saying at https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11049-022-09553-2.

It seems then you have been able to answer that particular question yourself. You had misunderstood what the author was saying. If you are still unsure where your misunderstanding lies, highlighting specific quotes from that article that make you believe that computational linguistics has helped with understanding Latin morphology that would go a long way to resolving the issues with the question.
Regarding your other questions, please take Draconis' advice to heart. Questions of that form are not answerable without a reason to believe the assertion in the first place. Please also make sure that any edits you make actually help the question, they should not simply be comments (which should go in the comments) or extra information with little to no relevance (which should be left out entirely), certainly do not replace the question with an unrelated one.

I have a hunch that OP may be banned from asking new questions (“I am against posting a new question”) which may explain why they’re editing old questions to ask something entirely unrelated (however undesirable).

if that's the case this would seem to constitute ban evasion which ought to get any restrictions on their account escalated
